# Typescript extends types any

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, formatting

Here is the decorator function:

```
const func = className => {
  let instance = new className();
  extendObservable(instance, instance.observables);
  return instance;
};

export default func;
```

Here is the class:

```
@func
class testClass {
  observables = {
    name: "",
    fname: "",
    age: 0,
  };
  .
  .
  .
  .
  someMethod() {
    let a = this.name  // <<<<< I'm getting property name does
                       //       not exist on type testClass
  }
}
```

How to remove this error without copying all the observables' properties to the class like that:

```
 name: string
 fname: string
 age: number
 observables = {
    name: "",
    fname: "",
    age: 0,
  };
```

Comment: this.observables.name

Comment: @VinodBhavnani but the function func extends the properties to the class ```extendObservable(instance, instance.observables);```, this.name exist, but how can I automatically extends the types too!